# Azure - WebApp + Database - How to deploy the db-schema and data

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-postgresql

We are using this [template](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoft.appservicewebappdatabasev3) from Azure.

DB used is "postgresql flexible-server" as DB from web app, we can connect to DB.

What is the best practice to deploy and execute DB/Table schema script on database server as one time process ?

E.g. using some extension on Server to deploy script, like we have for VM using DSC (desired state configuration) or CSE (Custome script extension)

Comment: If you were using SQL Server you can use a dacpac deploy to manage this. I'm not aware of any similiar tool for postgres. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Are you trying to deploy just schema in an ongoing process, or data as a once off? Postgres would have a backup/restore like anything else

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Thank you for comments, yes planning to deploy schema and data once. As DB server in this template is not accessible from public network and availble for access only through app service (linux based) need to know better way to do this.

Comment: _not accessible from public network and availble for access only through app service_ is this a specific networking configuration? You need to find some "compute" that has access to the database. and that "compute" needs access to storage (i.e. ADLS) that has the Postgres backup file. The compute could certainly be app service.